# Not seeing a diffraction pattern, what could be the cause?

Tags: optics, double-slit-experiment, home-experiment, experimental-technique

Basically took a piece of paper, cut out a small slit with some scissors, and held my phone's flashlight right on the slit. What could be causing the lack of diffraction?

Does the fact that the light source is held very close to the slit matter? Or is because of the fact that an LED light source was used?

Comment: You've given us very little information to work with (details matter here). You might find some hints in [the several previous questions about homemade version of this experiment](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/home-experiment+double-slit-experiment).

Comment: @dmckee In retrospect I might've held it too close to the wall. Is about one foot far enough to see a noticeable difference?

Comment: Details *matter*. For the question in your comment you have to worry about the width and separation of your slits. The classroom demo kit I use for my students works well with projection distances above a meter, but the slit separations are less than $1\,\mathrm{mm}$. The diffraction gratings I made with my departments laser printer needs a longer projection distance (8 meters gave 1.5 cm fringe separations). Cheap plastic diffraction grating can do the job with only $10\,\mathrm{cm}$ projection distance.

Comment: The slit is probably way too big. The bigger the slit, the smaller the diffraction pattern. The light from your phone is also probably not coherent enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of problems with your experimental set up which a really easily resolved and you will be able to see a white light diffraction pattern with very little effort.

What you need :
Some thin black (opaque) card about $\frac 13$ mm thick.  A pile of 15 sheets will be approximately 5 mm thick.
A really sharp Stanley/utility knife - I used a new blade.
A ruler preferably metal

The first problem is that you have used an extended source, the LED in you phone.
Cut ou a 3 mm sqaure of the black card and cut through it in one go a line about 10 mm long and this you will place on top of the light source in your phone.

Your next problems was that your slit was probably too wide.
So on another bit of your back card cut through it for a distance of about 10 mm.
This is the single slit which is going to produce the diffraction pattern.

Switch in the light in the phone and place the phone on a table.
Cover the light with the 3 mm square card adjusting its position so that emergent light has a maximum intensity.

Hold the other card about 400 mm above the card which is on the phone and orientate the slits so that they are approximately parallel to one another.
Look at the bottom slit through the top slit with the tip of your nose touching the top card. 
Do not have you eye too close to the top slit.

You should see a series of white/coloured bands as illustrated in the diagram below.
Moving and rotating the top slit about a vertical axis to improve the visibility of your single slit diffraction fringes.

[image]

---

When you used an extended source each part of the source resulted in a diffraction pattern offset from the other diffraction patterns that were being produced.
So you were see diffraction patterns offset from one another $\Rightarrow$ no visible diffraction pattern.

Whet you cut a slit you made it too wide which resulted in the fringes being too close to one another for you to see them.

A double slit is much harder to make!

Answer (score 0):

The coherence length of white light will work against you: use a laser pointer.  Secondly, ditch the paper and try two single edge razor blades.  You can glue them onto something so that you can hold them fixed.  If you have a small translation stage that will let you adjust the slit spacing by gluing one blade onto the moving part and one onto something fixed.  If not you could try making a highly oblique triangle (with the two razor blades as long ends) so that you can choose the slit spacing based on where you shine the laser (the slit width will taper to zero at the apex)  This will work if you get the slits close enough together.  Project onto white paper and voila.

Comment: Also a single wire like a guitar string works really good. Young’s very first interference experiment was a single human hair.